# How to copy from locally created python dags to locally installed dockertool box which is running with airflow image?

Tags: airflow, windows-8.1, docker-toolbox

I have installed puckel-airflow image on Windows 8 64 bit using docker toolbox.

I have created a a hello world Python scrpit ie,dag locally.

Now I wanted to transfer my Python scrpit dag from local machine to docker toolbox air flow image so that I can run the airflow image with specific tag.

Not able to find out proper step in order to copy from local c drive to dockertool box airflow image.

Note: using airflow bash inside dockertool box I have created a dags folder which it will place all the scripts to  that particular folder so that I can run the airflow python dags.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the approach....
Steps to follow.......
1)docker stop  ==== which is running

2)docker cp   <conatiner_id>:/usr/local/airflow/dags/
docker cp mymovedag.py  becccb825e16:/usr/local/airflow/dags/mymovedag.py

3)docker start <container_id>
docker start becccb825e16

4)docker exec -it --user  root <conatiner_id> /bin/bash
docker exec -it --user  root becccb825e16 /bin/bash

5)ls

6)cd dags

7)now you can see the file that is moved from windows to docker container